# Why does VS2019 suggest to convert a macro definition into a constexpr when using the C compiler?

Tags: c, visual-studio

A code like the one below in a header file entails a suggestion to convert the macro definition into a `constexpr` even when one is using the C compiler. What am I missing? There is no `constexpr`in C.

`#define BLAH 1`

Comment: Are you sure that you are compiling your program as a C program?

Comment: For sure. `Configuration properties > C/C++ > Advanced > Calling convention` gives me `Compile as C code`.

Comment: That property is actually just above the "Compile As" property. I think OP has just got confused when posting here. However, all those settings are both Platform- and Configuration-specific, so make sure both are set to "Active". Then, even though a property is set for the **Project**, that can be overridden for any/each/every **file** in the project. So, there are lots of places to check.

Comment: @EricPostpischil I made a mistake above. The statement should be `Configuration properties > C/C++ > Advanced > Compile As` gives me `Compile as C code (/TC)`

Comment: Use Help > Send Feedback > Report a Problem to let them know.

Comment: @AdrianMole Both the project and the `.c` file show `Compile as C code (/TC)`

Comment: @HansPassant I'll do that. Thanks to all.

Comment: @HansPassant The issue has already been reported several times in the "Developer Community". The first report was in December, 2018.

Comment: What is the exact warning or error output? Post a link to where it has been reported before. It may be helpful to others who run into the issue.